# Tomcat server in ubuntu is not running remotely

Tags: networking, firefox

I have installed tomcat server with java application in ubuntu 15.10. Tomcat server with Appln is running in server(locally). But issue is its not running in other system browser(Remotely). I tried all ways like port changes, SSL config, server.xml config, web.xml. Please let me know what is the solution exactly....Please help me..

I have attached the below remote tomcat web page error...

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at xxx.xxx.x.x:8080.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```